# Budgie 21.10 switching keyboard layouts problem

Tags: keyboard-layout

I have 2 layouts - English and Russian. After restart I can't type in Russian even though the keyboard indicator shows RU. Removing RU keyboard from input sources and adding it again helps. But only until next restart. Changing region format from UK to Russia doesn't help. Reordering input sources also has no effect. For the last 10 years I never had this problem with other Ubuntu flavours.

Comment: To disable IBus you need to add dpkg-divert: `sudo dpkg-divert --package im-config --rename /usr/bin/ibus-daemon`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see the following.

Budgie is GNOME based, so should act similar to GNOME. Like we it or not.
Both GNOME and Budgie uses XKB and Ibus; the latter is needed only for complex alphabets.
With default configuration Budgie should read `/etc/default/keyboard` (see example below)

```
cat << EOF | sudo tee /etc/default/keyboard 
# KEYBOARD CONFIGURATION FILE

# Consult the keyboard(5) manual page.

XKBMODEL="pc105"
XKBLAYOUT="us,ru"
XKBVARIANT=","
XKBOPTIONS="grp:alt_shift_toggle,grp_led:scroll"

BACKSPACE="guess"
EOF
```

and set keyboard layouts and their switching shortcut from it. Thus if you have `grp:alt_shift_toggle` (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>) defined here above, it should work.

To add necessary keyboard layouts you have to launch Keyboard settings (`gnome-control-center keyboard`) and add needed languages to Input Sources here.

If you want to set <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> for first time you'll need to install GNOME Tweaks by `sudo apt-get install gnome-tweaks --no-install-recommends` and set such shortcuts from it in *Keyboard & Mouse* → *Additional Layout Options* → *Switching to another layout*.

Then you'll need to add relevant applet to the Budgie Panel:

1. Launch Budgie Desktop Settings (`budgie-desktop-settings`)
2. Go to Top Panel tab
3. Click on `+` button to add *Keyboard Layout* applet
4. Optionally move *Keyboard Layout* to the needed part of Budgie Panel
5. Test keyboard layout change and make sure it changes on Budgie Top Panel.

Details are available at https://getsol.us/articles/configuration/configuring-keyboard-layout/en/ .

Note: if your issues persists this maybe permissions issue, you have to reset them by `sudo chown -R $USER:$USER ~/.cache ~/.config ~/.local` then reboot and retry above steps.

<sup>While writing this text I feel that both GNOME and Budgie are not viable for real life usage. It is good that fully featured alternatives like KDE, MATE and Xfce exists.</sup>

Comment: Thx. I will check it out. So far I'm using the default Super+Space.

Comment: Well, it didn't help. Even though I don't need Alt+Shift, I have installed GNOME Tweaks. Keyboard Layout applet has already been added. Funnily enough, setting Alt+Shift as a combination didn't switch the keyboard at all. The problem is still in place.

Comment: You may have some problems with Ibus, consider to disable it. Or try fresh user profile.

Comment: Hi N0rbert, I have added a dpkg-divert to disable IBus and after rebooting a couple of times everything seems fine. I will update my question if the problem persists. Thx mate!

Comment: Flying smoothly. Everything is all right. Disabling Ibus helped. Thank you for the advise.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same issue (in my case latam layout), and it was driving me crazy. Thank God I was able to solve it easily by using the IBus Preferences applet and setting the option: "Use system keyboard layout", under the Advanced tab.

Comment: Hi Fernando, thanks for sharing the hint. It does work too and even easier than disabling IBus. I just tried it. After reinstalling Budgie I ran into the same problem again.

Comment: ^ I think this is the solution to the actual problem. Seems like a bug on the part of Budgie that this isn't set by default. WFM.